# how to sort data in excel according to db record

Tags: php, mysql, excel

[image: card member table]

[image: attendance table]

attendance table and card member table join ON `card member.id = attendance.card_member_id`

In attendance table, the column `attendance_datetime` record both arrive and leave time
`typeid = 1 :arrive, 
typeid = 2 :leave`

[image]

I would like to output to the Excel of all attendance record of the same class
now i can output the record, but the attendance time is incorrect,
eg in the excel, for 1220160007, the correct arrival time is 15:01:07 an leaving time is 17:01:07

EXCEL OUTPUT

```
Date         Arrival Time   Leaving Time    
2017-11-23    15:01:07      17:15:07        1220160007
2017-11-23    15:45:41      17:01:07        1220160008
2017-11-23    15:25:41      16:59:40        1220160009
```

PHP Code

```
if (isset($_GET['classid'])) {
    $class_id = $_GET['classid'];
    echo $class_id;
    }

  //fromdate
  if (isset($_GET['datesearch'])) {
  $datesearch = $_GET['datesearch'];
  }
  //todate
 if (isset($_GET['datesearch2'])) {
  $datesearch2 = $_GET['datesearch2'];
  }

 //from date convert date format
 $from= date("Y-n-j", strtotime($_GET['datesearch']) )."<br>";  
 //to date convert date format
 $to = date("Y-n-j", strtotime($_GET['datesearch2']) ); 
//display table data from row 6
$rows = 6;

  $sql2 = "SELECT card_member.id, 
 card_member.class_id,card_member.eng_name,attendance.card_member_id,
 attendance.card_member_id,attendance.attendance_datetime,
 attendance.type_id,attendance.on_time
 FROM card_member 
 LEFT JOIN attendance ON card_member.id = attendance.card_member_id
WHERE str_to_date(attendance_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') 
BETWEEN str_to_date('$from','%Y-%m-%d' ) AND  str_to_date('$to','%Y-%m-%d')
AND
 card_member.class_id = '".$class_id."'";


 $result = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


$type_id = $row['type_id'];
$nametest = $row['eng_name'];


$attendance_datetime = $row['attendance_datetime'];
$on_time = $row['on_time'];

$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($attendance_datetime));

$cardId =$row['id'];


$cardmemberid =$row['card_member_id'];

$time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($attendance_datetime));


if ($on_time == '1') {
    $status = "On time";
} else if ($on_time == '0' && $type_id == 3) {
    $status = "Late & Early Leave";
} else if ($on_time == '0') {
    $status = "Late";
} else if ($type_id == 3) {
    $status = "Early Leave";
}


if ($type_id != 1 && $cardmemberid == $cardmemberid  ) {

    $rows--;
    $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$rows, "{$time}");
} 


else {

$sheet->setCellValue('A'.$rows, "{$nametest}")
          ->setCellValue('B'.$rows, "{$date}")
          ->setCellValue('C'.$rows, "{$time}")
          ->setCellValue('E'.$rows, "{$status}")
          ->setCellValue('F'.$rows, "{$cardmemberid}");

    $sheet->getStyle('B'.$rows)->getBorders()->getRight()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
    $sheet->getStyle('C'.$rows)->getBorders()->getRight()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
    $sheet->getStyle('D'.$rows)->getBorders()->getRight()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);

    $cardmemberid= $cardmemberid;



}

     $rows++; 
 }
```

I am wondering how to get the leaving time of a specific student to match his/her arrival time and display at the same row in excel .
Many thanks

Comment: You include a lot of information but it is unclear what you are asking.  `the attendance time is incorrect` on the Excel sheet?  I don't see any fields called 'attendance' in "Excel Output".  If you are referring to the values like "1220160007", that is obviously the **card_member_id** field (not a date field)

Comment: By incorrect, i mean the leaving time record isnt refer correctly to a specific person. eg Person A arrival time is 9:00 and her leaving time is 15:00, but in person A's row, the leaving time record is 16:00. And i think i kinda figure it out, by adding ORDER BY in the select statement, the issue is fixed. THank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

By adding ORDER BY in the select statement, the issue is fixed,thankyou

Comment: oh my, so your question should have been "How to sort records in MySQL".  The information and examples you gave were unrelated to the question and confused people.  But I am glad you figured it out.

Comment: OH.. i see, thank you for pointing that out, As a newbie sometime this's quite confusing, appreciate your help

Comment: no problem.  Makes sure to check out the [tour] and the tips at [ask] and [mcve]...  :-)